# Google market support null device

Tags: android

I have publish app in Google maret ,but it show support zero device.my manifest file :

```
android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

I use android 4.1 to compile ,thanks for your answer.

Comment: Post your whole manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you Define **android:minSdkVersion** as applicable by your Application. if your application should show in all version/density devices remove all compatible-screen and support-screen code from your Menifest File